# Had this Mirror Universe Terrans' trait ever been referred to before Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, mirror-universe

Spoilers ahead from the latest DIS episode! You have been warned.

In [DIS: Vaulting Ambition](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vaulting_Ambition_(episode)), we find out that:

> The Garbiel Lorca we have seen so far is actually his counterpart from the Mirror Universe. The unique trait that confirms this, is the light sensitivity, which is common to all Terrans in the Mirror Universe, according to Emperor Georgiou.

Has there been any confirmation about this trait in any previous Mirror Universe episode (especially those published before Discovery)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Burnham's comment in the previous episode (["The Wolf Inside"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wolf_Inside_(episode))), regarding the lower quality of light in the mirror universe, gives support for different evolutionary adaptations between the two human lines.

Comment: So, the Mirror Universe is darker in all aspects :)

Comment: Yeah, picking up the theme of "In A Mirror, *Darkly*", and running with it.

Comment: This reminds me of light therapy for countering [seasonal affective disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonal_affective_disorder).

Comment: So everyone is basically grumpy and mean all the time because it's so dark.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which explicitly asked about references to this trait *before Discovery*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Although the question prefers references to other series, it does not make that a requirement.  The preference wasn't even part of the question at the time I answered; it comes from a later edit of the question.

Comment: @Gaultheria: The explicit restriction "before Discovery" was in the question title since the [first version of the question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/179623/1).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - The subject line and question body of posts on this site sometimes have differences.  In this case, the question body initially included this request: "Has there been any confirmation about this trait in any previous Mirror Universe episode (from any series)?"

Comment: @Gaultheria: That does not contradict the question title.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Please stop.  I answered a question that the original poster asked.

Answer (score 2):

No. Light Sensitivity was not even known to be a trait of Terrans until Emperor Georgiou stated it.

Comment: While it's hard to prove a negative, it'd be better if you could edit in some evidence to back this up :)

Comment: @Jenayah I wonder though what type of evidence could be edited in? (evidence that something exists is easy to be put in but the contraray.....I daresay ouch)

Comment: @Thomas off the top of my head: previous mentions of Mirror Universe where light sensitivity could have played a part, but didn't; write'r's interview saying "no, light sensitivity is something Joe and I made up for episode XYZ, before that we never really thought about it"; a character bursting into a room saying something like "guys, I've discovered this thing that I call light sensitivity", implying that it wasn't known before... If this Stack has taught me anything, it's thinking of ways to prove a negative ;p